# How to create a macro, on Excel, that will open a new sheet and copy certain cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just looking for advice on how to create a macro that will copy cells from one sheet and open a new sheet and paste them in. I'm a complete beginner with VBA.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't write your code here at StackOverflow. Please post what you have tried, and the results that don't work...and ask for help.

Comment: Turn on the Developer Tab (method varies by excel version, but is easily found through a quick Google search), navigate to the Developer Tab, click "Record Macro", do whatever it is you want to do, click "Stop Recording", click "Visual Basic". Then, start learning to modify what got recorded to do more, be more flexible, etc.

Comment: That's a good question. I would do what @PaaquaGrant said or do a google search for `new worksheet VBA` or `copy and paste cells or range VBA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play around with the Record Macro option. Set the Developer tab to appear on your ribbon. I recorded this which is similar to what you are asking although I'm not sure if its everything you need.

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("A1:A8").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on the Macro Recorder and click through the steps.  You will learn a lot that way!  You certainyl won't learn how to write a loop, for instance, with the Macro Recorder, but you will learn a ton.